# made from/of rubber tires?

Tags: prepositions

Should "from" or "of" be used in the following?

> The shoes are made **from**/**of** rubber tires.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Made **of** a substance, made **from** something already made for some other purpose - made of glass, made from old Coke bottles, made of paper, made from old magazines.

Comment: What effort have you made in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "from" and "of" are slightly different.

We say "made of a substance" (made of rubber). But we say "made from something already made for some other purpose" (made from rubber tires).

For example "made of glass", but "made from old Coke bottles".  Or  "made of paper", but "made from old magazines".

These are only general trends in meaning, and not strict rules.

Comment: answer developed from comment by Michael Harvey.

Comment: Note: 'tyres' in the British English part of the world.